# Display Attachments Content on Visualforce Page or create pdf file

Tags: visualforce, community

I have 2-3 attachments of different types (pdf/image/text etc). I want to display content of all the attachments either on a single visualforce page or simply create pdf using Apex code. Is it possible? If yes how can i go for it?

We cannot use any Appexchanges or write java code or host webserver. Can use javascript if it's possible using that